# No scrolling at all after iScroll 5 library integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iscroll

I added the iScroll library on http://dev.bit.co.in

I've put in place the bare minimum. The entire body content is encapsulated by

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="scroller">
...
</div>
</div>
```

and in the head I put this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/themes/bit.co.in/js/iscroll-master/build/iscroll.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var myScroll;

function loaded () {
        myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper');
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

</script>
```

Also, to the body tag I added onload="loaded()" and in the CSS I added this:

```
@media (max-width: 430px) {
body {
        /* On modern browsers, prevent the whole page to bounce */
        overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;

        /* Prevent native touch events on Windows */
        -ms-touch-action: none;

        /* Prevent the callout on tap-hold and text selection */
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;

        /* Prevent text resize on orientation change, useful for web-apps */
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
        -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
        -o-text-size-adjust: none;
        text-size-adjust: none;
}

#scroller {
        position: absolute;

        /* Prevent elements to be highlighted on tap */
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);

        /* Put the scroller into the HW Compositing layer right from the start */
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
        -o-transform: translateZ(0);
        transform: translateZ(0);
}

}
```

These are the barebones changes recommended by iscroll.

Right now when I pull it up in mobile it doesn't seem to scroll at all
unfortunately.

If you have any ideas, let me know. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

I suspect the reason is this javascript code here:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var text_input = document.getElementById ('shortname-lookup');
    text_input.focus ();
    text_input.select ();
}
```

which overrides the `onload="loaded()"`. The `.onload` is a [traditional event registration](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) in which case there can only be one function attached to this handler using this method and it seems it also overwrites [inline events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html). As a demonstration, I made [**simple page**](http://jsbin.com/wifeb) up with these code

```
<body onload="alert('onload')">
<script>
window.onload=function(){
   alert('denied')
}              
</script>
```

There should only be one alert with "denied". (Though testing it, sometimes onload appears. But only onload)

### Solution

Use [`.addEventLister/attachEvent`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) either for loading iScroll or focusing you text. Something like

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    var text_input = document.getElementById ('shortname-lookup');
    text_input.focus ();
    text_input.select ();
});
```

or since you are using jquery anyway

```
 $(function(){ //shortcut for onload
   $("#shortname-lookup").select().focus()
 })
```

Comment: I actually had to look this up as I haven't asked a question before. But up triangle for upvote. Gray checkmark to accept answer. From http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: OK accepted, actually it tells me I need more reputation points to upvo, but anyway I put your solution live now on https://bit.co.in :) The only problem I'm having now is that anchor tags don't work anymore on mobile devices. Basically clicking a link doesn't take me anywhere.

Comment: Hm... checking out the source code, I don't see any red flags. On android device the links seems to work and I don't have an iOS and windows phone 8 device handy to check on those. Sorry.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I changed the myScroll declaration from myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper'); into myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { click: true });